# When addressing two people in an email, would you ever say "at your earliest conveniences" or "at your earliest opportunities"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases

When I send a form to a client and need them to sign I usually write "at your earliest convenience" or "at your earliest opportunity".
However I was composing an email in which I was speaking to two people that I needed to sign a form and I was wondering if it is grammatically correct to write "at your earliest conveniences" or "at your earliest opportunities". Can/should it be plural since I'm addressing two people?

Comment: It just sounds plain weird...I would not use plurals there. It is a set phrase.

Comment: Use of the plural implies multiple opportunities/conveniences. If that’s what you intend, go for it. Otherwise use the singular.

Comment: I vote plural. Sounds better than singular in addressing multiple people. What would you say to a roomful of people? Idiomatic usage of plural as Robusto points out. But so what, it's English

Comment: 'Could you each sign this at your earliest convenience.' You might prefer to hedge with a 'please' and/or a question mark.

Comment: I think you could get away with thinking of convenience as non-count in these set expressions.

Comment: Dying at Our Convenience. A briefing to the 64th Annual Meeting of the International Whaling Commission.

Comment: @Michael Harvey But then so, arguably, is 'conveniences' in 'I must use the conveniences'. Plural-form, but non-count. In OP's case, the plural form would be far less commonly used than the singular form.

Comment: I always think of a public lavatory as _a convenience_. Countable.

Comment: Any American looking for a "lavatory", "bathroom" or even WC would be confused with "convenience". AFAIK, it is BrE...